# Número de elementos no corresponde con tamaño de paginación

Tags: android-studio, jpa

El código en mi controlador es:

```
@Autowired
private INewsService newsService;

@RequestMapping(path = "/news", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public Page<NewsItem> listNews(@RequestParam(name="page", defaultValue = "0") int page ){
    Pageable pageRequest = new PageRequest(page, 4);

    Page<NewsItem> newsItemsList = newsService.getLastNewsItems(pageRequest);

    return newsItemsList;
}
```

Por lo que espero recibir 4 registros de los 12 que tengo en la base de datos. Pero cuando levanto el servidor, y me voy a `http://localhost:8080/news`
Recibo los siguientes elementos:

```
{
"content":
[{
"idNewsItem":1,"title":"noticia 1","content":"cuerpo 1","createDate":1623196800000
},
{
"idNewsItem":2,"title":"noticia 2","content":"cuerpo 2","createDate":1623283200000
},
{
"idNewsItem":3,"title":"noticia 3","content":"cuerpo 3","createDate":1623369600000
},
{
"idNewsItem":4,"title":"noticia 4","content":"cuerpo 4","createDate":1623456000000
},
{
"idNewsItem":5,"title":"noticia 5","content":"cuerpo 5","createDate":1623542400000
},
{
"idNewsItem":6,"title":"noticia 6","content":"cuerpo 6","createDate":1623628800000
}],
"totalPages":4,"totalElements":14,"last":false,"number":0,"size":4,"sort":null,"first":true,"numberOfElements":6}
```

Es decir, 2 elementos más cuando deberían ser 4.. esto no lo entiendo. Alguien sabe por qué pasa esto?